# input type range jquery

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, input, range

hello I try to use jquery plugin for making input type range work for FF and IE.

So I use the following code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Dokument bez tytułu</title>
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(":range").rangeinput();
  </script></head>

<body>
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="5" />

</body>
</html>
```

but it does not work with FF and IE, it just display an input type text.

Does anyone have an idea?

Kind Regards.

SP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='range']").rangeinput();
});
```

Comment: `type='range'` instead of `type=range`. I have removed my comment from answer to not make you angry :) Sorry, was not my intention.

Comment: @StanislasPiotrowski: With welcome

Comment: @SnakeEyes That doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @undefined: Depends on browsers. If you work on IE, won't work. I created a jsfiddle and run it under IE8. Without success. In other browsers, works great without quotes.

Comment: Not sure, I do not develop for that browser.

Comment: I believe you, I don't work too but the many people uses IE8 in Windows XP. IE is my first-class enemy :))